# python csv writer is adding quotes when not needed

Tags: python, json, csv

I am having issues with writing json objects to a file using csv writer, the json objects seem to have multiple double quotes around them thus causing the json objects to become invalid, here is the result:

```
"{""user.CustomAttribute.ISOLanguageCode"": ""en"", ""user.Email"": ""emzy1786@googlemail.com""
```

what I want is

```
{"user.CustomAttribute.ISOLanguageCode": "en", "user.Email"": "emzy1786@googlemail.com"}
```

here is how I open the file, perhaps there is an argument I can pass to prevent this from happening?

```
file = csv.writer(open(localResultPath + ".txt",'ab'),delimiter = '|')
```

here is how I write to the file, the last append adds the json as a string

```
list.append(pk)
list.append(email)
list.append(json)
file.writerow(list)
```

Comment: Could you please also show us how you actually write the to the opened file?

Comment: made changes please take a look

Comment: @Asad: That hardly matters here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switch off auto-quoting with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, and set `quotechar` to the empty string:

```
file = csv.writer(open(localResultPath + ".txt",'ab'), 
                  delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
```

Even with `csv.QUOTE_NONE` the `csv.writer()` will still want to quote the `quotechar` if left set to anything but an empty string, if present in the value. The default quote character is `"` and JSON values are full of those.

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
>>> writer.writerow(['{"user.CustomAttribute.ISOLanguageCode": "en"}'])
>>> f.getvalue()
'{"user.CustomAttribute.ISOLanguageCode": "en"}\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the quotechar to s.th. else than " :

```
csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',quotechar='&', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Make sure that the quote character does not appear in your objects, obviously.

If you switch off quoting you have to be careful when your delimiter appears in the JSON-Object as well.
Better way is using the `json` module and its functions `json.dump()` and `json.load()` for writing and reading the objects