# python csv writer not handling escaping '|' correctly

Tags: python, json, csv, escaping

I am attempting to write some JSON to a file, the following is the code used to open the file, please keep in mind i need the quoting and "quotechar" parameters to ensure the JSON is valid when written to a file.

```
file = csv.writer(open("myfile" + ".txt",'ab'),delimiter = '|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
```

For some reason if the JSON contains '|' an exception is thrown with the message "need to escape, but no escapechar set". Below is a a sample, is there a way of avoiding issues like this by passing a parameter when opening a file or in any other way?

```
"clickthrulink.Description": "|this is a test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an escape character to escape the `|` character inside JSON values. You need to re-use that same escape character when reading the CSV file again:

```
file = csv.writer(open("myfile" + ".txt",'ab'),
                  delimiter = '|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='',
                  escapechar='\\')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', escapechar='\\')
>>> writer.writerow(['{"clickthrulink.Description": "|this is a test"}'])
>>> f.getvalue()
'{"clickthrulink.Description": "\\|this is a test"}\r\n'
>>> print f.getvalue()
{"clickthrulink.Description": "\|this is a test"}
```

Comment: will this work for all scenarios? i am importing millions of lines here, is there a way of ensuring i wont see this issue again with other characters?

Comment: @godzilla: This will escape the *delimiter* so that a `csv.reader()` with the same configuration can still read your CSV data and not interpret the escaped delimiters in the values. So yes, this will work for all scenarios.

Comment: @godzilla: However, I do question your choice of CSV to write JSON values. Why not write JSON *only*? You can wrap your data in a outer dictionary or list, write that to the file line by line.

Comment: there are other fields i need to write besides the json, csv is used because i need to dump the results to a database. In the worst case scenario i can just write to a flat file but not ideal!

Comment: Right. So the database will import the CSV? Presumably the CSV reader on that side can handle quoting properly, why did you need to disable the quoting altogether? The standard dialect configuration usually works just fine.

Comment: well initially i had the following problem, where the json objects were becoming invalid as a result, my last concern will be populating the database but only time will tell whether that succeeded or not . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485940/python-csv-writer-is-adding-quotes-when-not-needed/22486098?noredirect=1#22486098

Comment: @godzilla: Yes, I am questioning if you had an actual or a perceived problem there. Your CSV data was being correctly escaped; quotes around the value, any quotes in the value doubled. That's a standard CSV dialect and if you read that data into Excel for example, the quoting would be reversed again for you.